# Search for a field which matches x % of input text with match_query

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm working on with `match_query` ElasticSearch and I'm facing a problem as described in the title.

Field name:  `project.name`

Its mapping:

```
    "project": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "owner": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
```

- For example, the user wants to search for the project's name: `the ranger 1`
- In the database only have `project.name` = `the ranger`
- `project.name` only matches 2 terms (`the`, `ranger`) out of 3 terms (`the`, `ranger` and `1`)

Is there any way to search all documents which has the `project.name` field matches at least 60% terms of query string?

Comment: google `minimum_should_match`

Comment: Thanks, But it is not what Im looking for because `minimum_should_match `  indicate the number of 'should' clauses in bool query should match.

Comment: can you check if my answer works for you? @tauitdnmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**: you can use minimum_should_match in a match query.

The match query is of type boolean. It means that the text provided is analyzed and the analysis process constructs a boolean query from the provided text. The operator flag can be set to `or` or `and` to control the boolean clauses (defaults to `or`). The minimum number of optional should clauses to match can be set using the minimum_should_match parameter. The analyzer can be set to control which analyzer will perform the analysis process on the text. It defaults to the field explicit mapping definition, or the default search analyzer.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "project.name": {
        "query": "the ranger 1",
        "minimum_should_match": "2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also specify percentages and some conditions. see here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html